# Field with same names from parent class and implemented interface and just inside one class difference

Tags: java, inheritance, field, member-hiding

research 2 code snippets

### Snippet 1:

```
interface Int1{
    String str = "123";
}
class Pparent{
    String str = "123";  
}
class F extends Pparent implements Int1{       
}
```

this code compiles normally.

### snippet2

```
class Pparent{
    String str = "123";
    public static String str = "123"; 

}
```

result: compile error with message

```
variable str is already defined in class
```

### Resolution

for me both snippets looks like same.

Why does I see different results

### update for Abimaran Kugathasan

you say:

> Fields in interface are implicitly public static, and there not
>   inherited to sub class

contr-example:

```
interface Int1{
    String str = "123";
}
class F implements Int1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(F.str);
    }
}
```

### I cannot write so

```
class F extends Pparent implements Int1{
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(str);
    } 
}
```

why? I work with static content only.

Comment: The compiler has a rule for determining which value to take in case 1, in case two, you have little hope of doing something useful so it is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for me both snippets looks like same.

They're clearly *not* the same. In your second snippet, you've got two variable declarations for the same name in the same class. That's a violation of this part of [section 8.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3):

> It is a compile-time error for the body of a class declaration to declare two fields with the same name.

In the first snippet, you're declaring one (implicitly static field in the interface and one field in the class. That doesn't violate any rules. Instead, it just follows this rule, also in section 8.3:

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I don't see how your update is relevant. You asked why your first snippet is valid and your second snippet is invalid - I've answered that. If you now want to ask a *different* question, you should do precisely that. (But basically, the instance field `str` in `Pparent` *hides* the static field `str` in `Int1`. This is just another reason to keep all fields private.)

Comment: I want to ask different but related question

Comment: So ask it as a new standalone question. Stack Overflow isn't designed to be a "conversation of questions" in a single post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810509/what-will-happen-if-fields-with-same-name-inherites-from-two-sourcesclass-and-i

Answer (score 2):

Fields in interface are implicitly `public static`, and **there not inherited to sub class**. So no conflicts.

In the second case, both fields are in the same class, so there will be conflicts. And compiler complains. as [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) says,

> It is a compile-time error for the body of a class declaration to
>   declare two fields with the same name.

Updated Answer based on updated question

```
interface Int1{
    String str = "123";
}
class F implements Int1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(F.str);
    }
}
```

Here, you aren't inheriting the field, you just access it, because, it's public and static, compiler will automatically change  `F.str` to `Int1.str`.

**In Java, static and inheritance won't work together.**

Comment: @gstackoverflow : Inheritance is different from accessing the field. In the updated question, you just accessing the filed of that interface

Comment: through class reference