# what will happen if fields with same name inherites from two sources(class and interface)

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, field, implementation

### valid code:

```
interface Int1{
    String str = "123";
}
class Pparent{
    String str = "123";  
}
class F extends Pparent implements Int1{       
}
```

### invalid code

add main method to F class:

```
class F extends Pparent implements Int1{
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(str);
    } 
}
```

outs

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>   The field str is ambiguous
>
>   at test.core.F.main(NullReferenceTest.java:45)
> ```

I don't see striking differs beetwen both variants.
I prepare to scjp and ask to clarify all related situations. When I see familiar question I am messed.

Can you clarify common rule ?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis http://ideone.com/gMqUpe

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis at link writes that **compiler!** said *reference to str is ambiguous, both variable str in Pparent and variable str in Int1 match*

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis in my question: *Unresolved **compilation** problem**. I think that exception in thread main - it is eclipse wrapper) Eclipse - bad boy)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: It's not that the compiled classes are out of sync. It's that Eclipse still emits class files even on compilation failure, and allows you to try to run the code (usually with a warning dialog).

Comment: @JonSkeet I see. I thought it happened when compiling with the interface without the field. Then adding the field, re-compiling the interface and trying to run the class. I realize that if the class is compiled without the interface field, it will refer to the instance field in the bytecode so what I was suggesting would not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fields which the identifier `str` can refer to - a static one inherited from `Int1`, and an instance one inherited from `Pparent`. Even though it's invalid to try to *use* the instance one from a static context, the name can still be *resolved*. (If `Pparent.str` were static, you'd still get the error message.)

Neither field is hiding the other, because they're inherited from different parents - so the name is ambiguous. The compiler's complaining because it doesn't know which field you mean.

If you want the one from `Int1`, just qualify it:

```
System.out.println(Int1.str);
```

If you want the one from `Pparent`, you should create an instance and cast it to `Pparent` to make it clear you're *not* referring to the interface field:

```
System.out.println(((Pparent) new F()).str);
```

Obviously this is horrible, and you should avoid getting into such situations in the first place. This is partly achieved by making all fields private, except constants. It's very unusual to have two constants with exactly the same name in both a superclass and an interface you want to implement.

Comment: It is strange for me because in my example instance of class doesn't exist. Logically to take availible static variable

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I understand that that would be useful in some ways, but I think it's just not how the language is defined. It's not easy to point out *exactly* where in the spec it states that though...

Answer (score 1):

The `str` field of your `interface Int1` is implicitly `static` `public` and `final`.

The `str` field of your `Pparent` class is an instance field.

What happens when you reference `str` is you have an ambiguous reference to the instance field and the class field, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not allowed , as value of ***str*** would be ambiguous between your `PParent` class and `Int1` ,this will give you compile time errors as you are getting currently.This is a case of multiple inheritence of variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run code inside Eclipse which has an error. Eclipse generates code to produce that message.

You are invoking that code generated by Eclipse. Your original source was erroneous, so the Eclipse compiler could not compile it - instead byte code has been generated that shows the message in the question.

Realistically,this is a Compile time error.